# overlay a raster layer over plot_3d

Tags: r, raster, rayshader

I am trying to implement this spectacular visualization tool and the only thing that seems to get in the way is to be able of overlapping raster layers over the 3dplot, How could that be possible? I tried add_overlay,but I cannot understand how to proceed from the error message.

```
library(raster)
library(rayshader)
altc=getData('alt', country='MOZ',mask=T)
elevation_matrix = raster_to_matrix(altc)

y=raster("https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhsu204du0rgbjp/Tlim_margins_Mozambique.grd?dl=0")

mat_reduced <- resize_matrix(elevation_matrix, 0.7)

mat_reduced |>
sphere_shade(texture = create_texture(lightcolor = "white",
shadowcolor = "black",
leftcolor = "grey",
rightcolor = "grey",
centercolor = "grey",
cornercolors = c(NW = "#ffc500",
NE = "#387642",
SW = "#d27441",
SE = "#296176")),
colorintensity=0.12,
 sunangle = 45) |>

plot_3d(mat_tx_reduced,
windowsize = c(800, 600),
zscale = 200,
zoom = 0.65,
phi = 80,
theta = 0,
fov = 0,
shadow = TRUE,
shadowcolor = "#5da5da",
 water = TRUE,
watercolor= "lightblue",
 waterlinecolor="lightblue")|>
 add_overlay(overlay=y, alphalayer = 0.5)
 Error in .local(x, i = i, j = j, ..., value) : unused argument (value)
```

Comment: I can't run your code:  it refers to objects `mat_tx_reduced` and `y` that you didn't include.

Comment: thank you but you can actually get these objects from the previous lines of code.